# How to read the new bearer token in net 8 client app (maui blazor in my case)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, bearer-token, maui-blazor

I want to read the bearer token given by the .net 8 new identity api out of the box endpoints, but they are not JWT. In the past I used the following code to do this:

```
 var jsontoken = handler.ReadToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken) as JwtSecurityToken;

 string userID = jsontoken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId).Value;
 string name = jsontoken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName).Value;
 string role = jsontoken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Type == "role").Value;
 string email = loginModel.Email;
```

Now the ReadToken method gives an error saying the token is not of the type expected.

I have no idea what else to try really

Comment: .NET8 has made some changes. You may refer to [Bearer token authentication handler](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-7/#bearer-token-authentication-handler).

Comment: yes, but how do you read the token in a client app now?

Comment: You may refer to this : [ASP.NET Core Blazor authentication and authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0). The [AuthenticationStateProvider service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authenticationstateprovider-service) can provide the current user's ClaimsPrincipal data.